# What exactly is dynamic linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, theory

i have to create a dynamic linked list in C but i am not sure what exactly i have to do. What does mean dynamic? It is a list that u know what node where to find (array of *p to every nodes? But in this way, is it still considered as linked list?) or something Like every node has *p to next and previous node? Or if user says he wants to know exact position of node, is there a way to go exactly to that position?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and edit your question

Comment: I think a linked list is "dynamic" by definition. It is a data structure in which you can insert and delete nodes, only being limited by the amount of available memory. That means it uses `malloc` to get memory for new nodes, and `malloc` implies "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

In C, the word *dynamic* usually implies *allocated from the heap*, as opposed to *static* which refers to global objects defined and/or initialized at compile time.

I personally have never used the term *dynamic linked list*. It seems natural for list items to be allocated from the heap, at runtime (hence *dynamically allocated*). Yet it is possible to define static objects that are linked as a list at compile time. I may have used this approach in some cases.

A third type of object could be used in list: nodes with automatic storage, that is defined as local variables. This is possible, but **very** tricky because these objects go out of scope when the function exits so the list becomes invalid if it still links to them.

As a conclusion, the type of lists you are expected to deal with are just plain vanilla linked lists with nodes allocated from the head with `malloc` or `calloc`, and freed with `free` when discarded.